# Verifying the certificate chain with OpenSSL

Tags: certificate, openssl, rsa

I require the OpenSSL command to verify the certificate chain. In the certificate, the signature hash is signed by the signer's private key.

Comment: What have you attempted? Have you [read the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.html)

Comment: "I am unable to use..." -- why? Did you try? What was the output?

Comment: From documentation I cannot find how to decrypt message using pkeyutl with public key of rsa. What is the corresponding command for it?

Comment: You're not actually encrypting with the pivate key. `rsautl -encrypt` (also `-verify`) accepts a privatekey _file_ as input -- _or_ a publickey file or a certificate file -- but uses only the publickey from it, extracted in the same fashion as `rsa -pubout` or `pkey -pubout`.

Answer (score 0):

OP, please note that *signing a message* is not the same as *encrypting the message using the private key*.  As [@dave_thompson_085](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/39571/dave-thompson-085) points out [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/can-openssl-decrypt-the-encrypted-signature-in-an-amazon-alexa-request-to-a-web) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143213/how-to-verify-a-server-key-exchange-packet), this is a [frequently repeated but incorrect trope](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/can-openssl-decrypt-the-encrypted-signature-in-an-amazon-alexa-request-to-a-web), which tends to lead to confusion, as it did this case.  Some have speculated that the cause of this misconception stems from the *deleterious effects of post-Disco pop music* (see [@Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin)'s answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87325/if-the-public-key-cant-be-used-for-decrypting-something-encrypted-by-the-privat)), but we'll never know for sure.

Having said that, `openssl pkeyutl` can be used to create digital signatures and verify digital signatures.  Using the keys created above, we can use the signer's private key (private.pem) to sign the message (message.txt) and store the signature in a file (signature.bin) like so:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -in message.txt -inkey private.pem -out signature.bin
```

Then, given the signer's public key (public.pem), the message (message.txt) and the signature (signature.bin), we can verify the signature, like so:

```
openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey public.pem -sigfile signature.bin -in message.txt
```

The above command should produce:

```
Signature Verified Successfully
```

OP commented that he is interested in using openssl to verify the signatures in a certificate chain.  If you've downloaded the certificate chain (e.g. using `openssl s_client`), then this can be done using `openssl verify`.  See https://www.misterpki.com/openssl-verify/ for a good write-up on this.

If you are interested in actually rolling up your sleeves, and seeing for yourself the heavy lifting that `openssl verify` is doing under the hood to verify the signatures in the certificate chain - then this requires parsing information from x509 certificate structures, and getting into the weeds with ASN.1 and DER formatting, etc.  Have a look at https://kulkarniamit.github.io/whatwhyhow/howto/verify-ssl-tls-certificate-signature.html for a good walk-through on this.

Comment: I require this command to verify the certificate chain. In certificate the signature hash is signed by the signers private key.

Comment: That's not at all what you ask for in your question ... You are confusing quite a few concepts together.

Comment: I agree with @schroeder, there is a lot to unpack here.  OP, please see what I appended to my answer above.

Comment: Also we (well, the migrated-from Stack) have https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127095/manually-walking-through-the-signature-validation-of-a-certificate which I think is pretty good (disclosure: I contributed much of part 4)